# access to translation in form label

Tags: php, symfony, translation

Currently, when I create a form using the FormBuilder, Symfony (3.3.5) show me a warning in the profiler that tell me there are no translation message for the given locale.

I followed the instructions in the symfony's documentation, but the problem still persistant.

My translation file is located here: `app/Resources/translations/properties.fr.yml`
and my config.yml file looks like this:

`parameters:
    locale: fr
framework:
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['%locale%']
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/app/Resources/translations'`

the file just contains this:

```yml
properties:
    zipcode:
        label: 'Code postal du bien'
```

and finally the form is created like this:

```php
$property = new Properties();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($property)
  ->add('zipCode', Type\IntegerType::class, array(
    'attr' => array(
      'min' => '10000',
      'max' => '99999'
    ),
    'label' => 'properties.zipcode.label'
  ))
  ->getForm();
```

Why my translation file is not used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an attribute to your field like this:

```
$property = new Properties();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($property)
  ->add('zipCode', Type\IntegerType::class, array(
    'translation_domain' => 'yourDomain',
    'attr' => array(
      'min' => '10000',
      'max' => '99999'
    ),
    'label' => 'properties.zipcode.label'
  ))
  ->getForm();
```

Replace "yourDomain" by your domain (file name). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

The deault translation domain is 'messages'. So you could change properties.fr.yml to messages.fr.yml. Another possibility is to change the translation domain like so:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
       'data_class'         => 'Acme\Entity\DemoEntity',
       'translation_domain' => 'properties'
    ]);
}
```